# Do we need to build and pay for an item only once

Tags: xcom-2

I've noticed when building some items, that they are available for all soldiers (e.g. the more powerful blades). So is this how it works on XCOM-2?
You build an armor type only once and it is available to the entire team?
Or is this true only for some of the items to be built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true for weapons and armor not built at the Proving Grounds.

It's *not* true for utility items and weapon-attachments, and anything built at the Proving Grounds.

Comment: In the case of armor, this is true only for the basic armor for each tier, and not for specialized armors!

Comment: @STTLCU Huh. That's kinda confusing.....

Comment: @SimonW Well, when you build the predator armor (the first upgrade for your normal kevlar armor), all the soldiers can use it for free. But EXO armor and Spider armor must be built one by one.

Comment: @Aurelius it is true for the snipers pistol tho, all weapons are upgraded for everyone, as are the nade luncher, gremlin, sword, and psi device

Comment: @Gilsham I think you misunderstand me. The pistol, a secondary weapon, only needs to be purchased once. Nanoscale vests, a utility item, must be purchased multiple times if you want multiple copies.

Answer (score 2):

When you build an item in the Proving Ground, you only get 1 copy of it each time. So, for example, if you want to equip your entire squad with any of the following types of armors:

1. Spider suit
2. E.X.O. suit
3. Wraith suit
4. W.A.R. suit

then you'll need to build one for each soldier.

Weapon and class items built in engineering only need to be purchased once:

1. Rifles (Specialists and Psi Operatives)
2. Gremlins (Specialists)
3. Psi Amps (Psi Operatives)
4. Shotguns (Rangers)
5. Swords (Rangers)
6. Cannons (Grenadiers)
7. Grenade Launchers (Grenadiers)
8. Sniper rifles (Snipers)
9. Pistols (Snipers)

Medium class armor can also be purchased once for your entire squad, unlike the light and heavy armors from the Proving Ground:

1. Predator armor
2. Warden armor

All other items built in engineering will only give you 1 new copy for each purchase.

Comment: I think you missed plasma grenades..?